# R Markdown will not knit at all

Tags: r, r-markdown

My Rmarkdowns will no longer knit, every file give the same error.

Under the Render window, it says:

> Error in library(emo) : there is no package called ‘emo’
> Execution halted

However, **I have **never** used a package** called `emo` and that package is certainly not in this empty .Rmd file

I've tried updating R and RStudio, I'm just quite lost. Any guidance would help!

Here is my code, I haven't changed a single thing after opening the new .Rmd. has

````
---
title: "knitting_test"
author: "XXXXX"
date: "1/20/2022"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:


```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

Comment: ```install.packages("emo") -> restart RStudio -> knit```

Comment: You may not need to restart RStudio, just install `emo` and try to re-knit.